# Why won't my extracted data from Spotify's API store in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have connected to Spotify's API in Python to extract the top twenty tracks of a searched artist.  I am trying to store the data in MySQL Workbench in a database named 'spotify_api', I created called 'spotify'.  Before I added my code to connect to MySQL Workbench, my code worked correctly and was able to extract the list of tracks, but I have run into issues in getting my code to connect to my database.  Below is the code I have written to both extract the data and store it into my database:

```
    import spotipy
    from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

    import mysql.connector


    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = "localhost",
        user = "root",
        password = "(removed for question)",
        database = "spotify_api"
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spotify_api.spotify;'
    mycursor.execute(sql)

    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="(removed for question)",
                                                           client_secret="(removed for question)"))

    results = sp.search(q='sza', limit=20)

    for idx, track in enumerate(results['tracks']['items']):
        print(idx, track['name'])
        sql = "INSERT INTO spotify_api.spotify (tracks, items) VALUES (" + \
            str(idx) + ", '" + track['name'] + "');"
        mycursor.execute(sql)

    mydb.commit()
 
    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM spotify_api.spotify;")

    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    for x in myresult:
        print(x)

    mycursor.close()
```

Every time I run my code in the VS Code terminal, I receive an error stating that my table doesn't exist.  This is what it states:
"mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1146 (42S02): Table 'spotify_api.spotify' doesn't exist"
I'm not sure what I need to fix in my code or in my database in order to eliminate this error and get my data stored into my table.  In my table I have created two columns 'tracks' and 'items', but I'm not sure if my issues lie in my database or in my code.

Comment: Seriousy? First you drop the table if it exists, then you try to insert data into the table that you have just deleted without recreating it...

Comment: I understand that seems obvious now that you point it out, but I have only learned a minimal amount of SQL so I didn't know what the issue was before.  Thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems pretty clear. You ran

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spotify_api.spotify;
```

...

```
INSERT INTO spotify_api.spotify (tracks, items) VALUES ...
```

We won't even raise the spectre of the Chuck Berry
track titled [little ol' Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327) here.

You DROP'd it, then tried to INSERT into it.
That won't work.
You'll need to CREATE TABLE prior to the INSERT.

Comment: @ J_H thank you for the explanation, it is definitely quite clear once you point out what I've coded incorrectly and what I should've coded instead, and my code now works!